# Determine where the functions are differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

Determine where the functions are differentiable
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}$$
I have calculated the derivative
$$f'(x) = - \frac{1}{(x-1)^2 \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}}$$

the problematic point for the derivative would be x=1 (but also for f(x)) and all the x, for which $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ < 0 i.e for $ x > -1 \land x<1$ (but the function is also not defined there). So everywhere else it would be differentiable?

---

$$g(x)=\frac{(2x-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

$$g'(x)=\frac{x+1}{({x^2+1})^{3/2}}$$

so for g'(x) I can not see any calues where problems would arise for the derivative.

---

Would that be correct?

Comment: Everythings looks correct to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ will be differentiable at any $x$ such that $\frac{x+1}{x-1}>0$ (I'm implicitly requiring the quotient to be well-defined, so that $x=1$ is out), by the chain rule. You need to be careful with the case $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=0$ (i.e. $x=-1$), because $t\mapsto \sqrt{t}$ is not differentiable at $0$. You'd have to study the behaviour at $-1$ by definition using the limit of the incremental quotient. Note that you can at most have a one-sided derivative, since $f(x)$ is not defined for $-1<x<1$. Try checking for yourself.

The function $g$ has a derivative everywhere, since it is the quotient of two everywhere differentiable functions, with the denominator being never $0$.